# Checking the registry in the Launch conditions in Advance installer

Tags: setup-project, installation-package, advanced-installer

Here is the scenario. I am using app1 to print into the registry when users have certain parameters like a specific username and a computer name. Once its checked then I need to launch the main application. Is there any way that I can check the registry key in the launching conditions?

Details about the problem:

I have three applications, App1, App2, and App3. I have combined all these in an [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com). App1 prints out a key to registry when the user has the proper username and computer name. I have put App1 in the pre-requisites. App2 is the one that sets the timeline of the application, so basically app2 prints out another key to the registry. I have put app2 in the featured based installation folder. App3 is the main application that needs to deployed on the user computer. I don't know how to do that? I have tried some multiple scenarios but its not really working out for me. I thought if during the Launch of main application I can check if the registry has both keys if yes then install the application3 if not then tell the user that you are not authorized user for the application. I don't know how to do that?

If any more details needed, please comment or ask me!

Thank you for all the efforts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keys from both App1 and App2 need to be checked by the launch conditions from App3 than you need to have them both added as pre-install prerequisites, not feature-based, so they get installed before App3 is launched.

After you have added the two prerequisites you need to create a [custom launch condition](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-professional.html#launch-conditions), using registry searches. The example I linked is using a file search, but you can easily adapt it to a registry search.

Comment: Great Answer! I basically implemented using the same logic for the registry. Also put the app2 into the prerequisites and not to the feature based files. Thanks Bogdan!